# How to suppress insert in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I want to create a BEFORE CREATE TRIGGER that checks if some restrictions apply, and if they don't, it stops the row from being added. I know i can access specific values of the added item with the NEW keyword, but how can i command mysql to suppress the insertion?

Comment: Have you seen [MySQL Data Validation on Insertion] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516839/mysql-data-validation-on-insertion) post on StackOverflow, It seems related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your trigger You can stop your insert using SIGNAL keyword as below

```
  if(<your condition>) then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your error message';
  end if
```

This will stop inserting